# Bash Script for Submitting Job on Cluster

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, export, cluster-computing

I am trying to write a script so I can use the 'qsub' command to submit a job to the cluster.

Pretty much, once I get into the cluster, I go to the directory with my files and I do these steps:

`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/program/bin`
Then,
`program > run.log&`

Is there any way to make this into a script so I am able to submit the job to the queue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Putting the lines into a bash script and then running `qsub myscript.sh` should do it.